# Firebase ios sdk async and threads

Tags: ios, firebase

Does anyone know whether remote calls to Firebase using Firebase iOS SDK use main thread or a background thread?

I couldn't find anything in documentation.

Comment: Can you elaborate as to why the question is being asked? i.e. there may be other solutions.

Comment: Cause I want to understand whether I need to use background thread to make async calls with Firebase SDK or I need to switch to main thread in Firebase callback clousures to use UI

Comment: Firebase handles that for you. All of the Firebase calls can be done asynchronously which eliminates the need to have to worry about threading. You may have a special case but if you are leveraging Firebase to handle your data, let it do the heavy lifting. If you have not done so yet, follow the getting started guide and code up a small app to get a feel for it. [Getting Started](https://www.firebase.com/docs/ios/quickstart.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firebase uses it's own background thread. But as Jay mentioned in the comments, Firebase eliminates the need to worry about threading.

So essentially there's no need to run Firebase in your own background thread.

Comment: You don't have to worry about threading- except if you want the completion block to do something on the UI thread!

Comment: @David East, what do you think about [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40076415/invalidating-timer-sometimes-not-working?noredirect=1#comment67426068_40076415) problem?

Comment: @Cesar actually, the completion block is run on the main (UI) thread

Answer (score 6):

Firebase does not entirely eliminate the need to worry about threading. Because Firebase callbacks always return on the main thread, you need to be especially careful when calling Firebase observe/ observerSingleEvent from the background thread.

Consider the use case:

```
DispatchQueue.global(qos: DispatchQoS.QoSClass.userInitiated).async {[weak weakSelf = self] in
 // Do something computationally intensive

 ref.child(somePath).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
  DispatchQueue.global(qos: DispatchQoS.QoSClass.userInitiated).async {[weak weakSelf = self] in {
   // Do some computationally intensive non-critical activity based on data retrieved from Firebase
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: Can you give a little more detail on what's wrong with the use case you've detailed?

Comment: Exactly, as of Dec 2019, Firebase 'observeSingleEvent' callbacks still return on the main thread, and this behavior CAN indeed be dangerous. For instance, I had a race condition caused by a Firebase callback accessing with T1 a variable also accessed by the same thread T20 that spawned the Firebase call, few instructions later.

Comment: @martin how did you fix this?

Comment: @TomGatward I wrapped the code that runs inside the callback into a specific DispatchQueue, i.e., DispatchQueue.global(qos: .utility).async { ... }, which is the same queue that spanned the Firebase call in the first place. In this way, I'm sure that the queue processing the code inside the callback is the same that called it, and that the code does not run on the main thread.