# Firebase crashes out of the blue with "RepoExists" message

Tags: ios, objective-c, firebase

My Firebase project (iOS, written in Objective-C) was working fine until out of the blue, when launching the app on the simulator, it crashes and I get this message:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'RepoExists', reason:
>   'createRepo called for Repo that already exists.'

I've tried deleting the derived data, restarting Xcode, etc. but to no avail, I can't find anything about this crash on Stack Overflow, Google or the Firebase docs either. Does anyone have any ideas?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: I am getting this too. This is a new crash I am seeing on Crashlytics but am unable to reproduce it on my own. Hopefully you can find a solution and share it here.

Comment: I did figure out it's happening when I check for a current user in the viewDidAppear function of my main login view controller. The exception breakpoint breaks on a memory address and not in actual code though. I'll investigate more and keep you posted of course.

Comment: Any update on this? I am seeing this repeatedly now.

Answer (score 8):

I moved the Database.database().ref() call to the main thread, solved the issue for me...

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. If you have  `Database.database().ref()` on a background thread your app will crash.

Comment: Additionally, based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33793174/7245977) there really isn't a reason to be executing Firebase calls on a background thread since they are already executed in the background.

Comment: @DoesData there are other reasons for doing so.

Answer (score 1):

I do this and it helped to solve my problem, I have `FirebaseManager` and there are two methods, one of them is the configure that I call in `AppDelegate` in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`. I also call `createDatabase` in `configure`

```
private func createDatabase() {
    _ = Database.database().reference()
}
```

After that, you can create a `DatabaseReference` in any other thread.

Answer (score 0):

Well I might be late for this, But I figured it out if you try to register a user that already exists on FirebaseDatabase, it will bring up this error.